# How to Enable Einstein Case Classification in developer org

Tags: servicecloud, einstein

Could anyone please help me in order to let me know how could I enable Einstein Case Classification in my developer org. I read a lot of documents, Salesforce help page, Release notes but didn't get an appropriate path. Do I need to contact Salesforce support team for this?

Answer (score -1):

On a DEV SandBox in order to be able to do this, you can follow the steps below

1. Be sure you are using Lightning
2. On Settings > Company information match production licenses
3. Activate ECC here, Feature Settings > SETUP > SERVICE CLOUD EINSTEIN > Einstein Case Classification

Comment: That would be applicable for a sandbox. The post suggests that they are using a Developer Edition, although it's not entirely clear.